# Protecting nose against Python interpreter crashes

Tags: python, unit-testing, boost-python, nose, python-bindings

We have a bunch of tests that call Python C/C++ bindings. We run these tests with nose:

```
nosetests myapp
.....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.009s
```

Sometimes, it happens that our bindings are buggy, causing the Python interpreter to crash, say, on test number 3:

```
test03_badcode (myapp.tests.test_badcode) ... Segmentation fault
```

Question: What is the best way to recover from this? Ideally, I would prefer nose handled these crashes itself<strike>, but I understand this is impossible to achieve</strike>. The next solution I thought of would be to take note of the test and re-start nose, now skipping the bad test. In my example, this would mean to execute tests 1, 2, 4 and 5, but **not** test 3. Is there a way to achieve this programatically with nose? Any other better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual with nose, there's a plugin for that.  [Insulate](http://code.google.com/p/insulatenoseplugin/) will run each test in a separate process.  That will slow things down, but you're guaranteed that a crash in one test won't affect the others.

Comment: Good catch, but somehow this plugin does not work correctly with skipped tests. I'm getting an exception `RuntimeError: Protocol error in master/slave communications`. Have you got an easy fix for that?

Comment: After looking at the module, we have created [a version of the plugin](https://github.com/idiap/bob/blob/master/python/bob/test/insulate.py) that supports skipped tests. This seems to work correctly in our builds.